# How can I fake an "AlternatingColumnsDefaultCellStyle" for the DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

DataGridView has an "AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle," which works like a champ. But I need the opposite sort of demarcation/decoration. Is there a property that can get the column backgrounds to be a different color than the default, or do I need to write code for the CellFormatting event, or...?

### UPDATE

OK, this seems odd:

With this code, from Ascension:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[i].ItemStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue;
```

...I get:

*'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn' does not contain a definition for 'ItemStyle' and no extension method 'ItemStyle' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

However, if I enter just the first part (*dataGridView1.Columns[i].*), I DO get "ItemStyle" via Intellisense as a valid option to select, but then it turns red when I do (possibly a Resharper effect). A dot after that allows the BackColor property to be selected, which is then NOT red.

Why is this bizarre behavior occurring, and is there a workaround?

And: Do red Intellisense items indicate inaccessibility, and if so, why are they displayed? Are "teaser" members of any value?

### UPDATE 2

This works (inspired by Ascension, so I'm giving him/her the correct answer):

```
DataGridViewCell cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Wheat;
dataGridView1.Columns[i].CellTemplate = cell;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DataGridView Property -> Misc -> Columns ... -> ItemStyle -> BackColor
```

or the script below

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    GridView1.Columns[i].ItemStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                }
                else
                {
                    GridView1.Columns[i].ItemStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue; ;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not with DataGridView was GridView.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting color for each column by going to
 DataGridView Property -> Misc -> Columns (open collection) ->  DefaultCellStyle

Comment: I'll Czech that out when I get to work; however, I failed to mention that the columns and rows in my DGV are created dynamically.